# Will my site containing duplicate content be accepted in Adsense

Tags: google, google-adsense, content

I've a new site just over 6 months with >50 unique visitors daily. It has good amount of duplicate pages which are not copyrighted. For example I've copied related companies product FAQ's "as is" in the site. Moreover I'm not supposed to modify a company's product's faqs.
I fear my login may be banned by Adsense if I submit it.

So I want to know:
1) Whether I can submit it for Adsense account
2) Whether Google can penalize me and in what way
3) How would Google come to know that the duplicate content on my site is not copyrighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `canonical` tag to indicate where any copied content originally comes from:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/original-content.html" />
```

You shouldn't be penalized if you are not doing anything deceptive.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Will Adsense team consider this tag?

Comment: Do you have any reference to anything that's concerning you? If you're not doing anything wrong you shouldn't have a problem because you could get it reviewed if they make a mistake and ban you.

Comment: Also, I'm a programmer not a lawyer so this could be wrong but my understanding is that there's no real way for content not to be copyrighted as it defaults to the creator when there's no other licenses/contracts etc in the way. I guess the details depend on your location but if you're legally allowed to use the content then there should be some way (or even requirement) of you placing notification of that onto your site. For example, the answers to these questions are the copyright of stackexchange but you're allowed to copy them as long as you attribute it back (see the footer of the page).